# Executor service to run every x seconds

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the correct way to get an executor service to submit every x number of seconds?

```
public void start() {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            ScheduledFuture<Integer> result = executorService.schedule(value, x, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    });
}
```

Would wrapping the contents of the run method in a while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) be a valid approach - if not how should this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Check out `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay` from a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some work
    }
}, 0, x, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // execute every x seconds
```